# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs': 'gs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Trying to execute this command:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(os.path.join(data_dir,pdf),flavor='lattice')
```

I'm trying to read a pdf in lattice flavor, but I keep getting this error related to ghostscript which I've already installed:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs': 'gs'
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Double check you path and file name ;) try print(os.path.join(data_dir,pdf)) and see if it whether it is your file path.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Even if Ghostscript is installed, it seems that is not accessible through python. I suggest you check that you can call `gs` from the command line as the user running the python script.  You can also try to call `gs` from the python REPL, by calling `python` from the command line and run the following lines:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['gs', '--version'])
```

If it is not found try to add the path where the `gs` binary is located to the `PATH` environment variable.